# Add Start up Registry Value for a ClickOnce C# Console Application

Tags: c#, .net, windows, visual-studio-2017

I am learning C# programming and building a simple ClickOnce application. I know this question has been asked before, I tried to take guidance from there but as nobody has given the full code (with all using statements etc.) I am getting some errors. So the posts I have come across, I could not comment on any of those to request the full since I need minimum of 50 reputations which I don't have being a beginner.

So here is my code for my simple program:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.Win32; // for registry

namespace MyRegApp
{
  class Program
  {
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Hello World!");

        // add to start up registry
        // The path to the key where Windows looks for startup applications
        RegistryKey add = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey("SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Run", true);
        add.SetValue("MyApp", "\"" + Application.ExecutablePath.ToString() + "\"");

        Console.WriteLine("Progam installed successfully, please press any key to exit");
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
  }
}
```

But in Visual Studio 2017, Application in Application.ExecutablePath gets a red underline and I get the error that "the name Application does not exist in the current context", or something (screenshot attached).

[Error Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KUA6Q.png)

Could you please advise if I need to put the registry bit in another method, or in another file, or how can I make it to work.

======= Edit =========

Having fixed the compile issue, I have now run into another problem. I am getting permission errors when I attempt to write to the registry. I have consulted some other posts but have not found anything similar. Below is my current version of code with a snippet for granting myself all necessary permissions, any help will be much appreciated.

```
namespace MyRegApp
{
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        // The code provided will print ‘Hello World’ to the console.
        Console.WriteLine("Hello World!");

        // add to start up registry
        RegistryKey key = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey("SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Run", true);
        RegistrySecurity rs = new RegistrySecurity();
        rs = key.GetAccessControl();
        string currentUserStr = Environment.UserDomainName + "\\" + Environment.UserName;
        rs.AddAccessRule(new RegistryAccessRule(currentUserStr, RegistryRights.WriteKey | RegistryRights.ReadKey | RegistryRights.Delete | RegistryRights.FullControl, AccessControlType.Allow));

        try
        {
            key.SetValue("MyRegApp", "\"" + Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().CodeBase.ToString() + "\"");
        }
        catch (SecurityException e) {
            Console.WriteLine("Security Exception:\n\n{0}", e.Message);      
        }

        Console.WriteLine("Progam installed successfully, please press any key to exit");
        Console.ReadKey();
    }

}
}
```

Comment: You'd need to run your app as administrator otherwise you won't have permission to write to a LocalMachine registry key. Or you could use `Registry.CurrentUser` instead of `Registry.LocalMachine`

Comment: Fantastic! It works thank you, I can now write a key to my registry. But for some reason it won't start at start up even with the start up registry key being present. I will keep researching this issue further.

Comment: Rather than rewriting your existing question, which was already resolved, you should ask another question, linking back to this one for reference.  You're much more likely to get peoples' attention with a new question (with a its own [mcve]) than with a re-edited closed question.  Relatedly, see [Can I ask only one question per post?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/222735) for which the answer is *One question per post*.

Comment: @dbc Thank you for your constructive feedback, appreciate that.

Answer (score 1):

[`Application.ExecutablePath`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.application.executablepath?view=netframework-4.7.2) requires a reference to the `System.Windows.Forms` namespace.

If you're wanting the executable path of a console application, try using `Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().CodeBase` instead. You'll need to reference the `System.Reflection` namespace.

Comment: It compiles perfectly now, thank you. I am now getting security permission errors when writing to registry. I have updated my original post with this code now, could you please check and advise @trix.